# Capturing an image to byte array in HTTP module and redisplaying it in future responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I want to write an HTTP module that caches image responses and replays the response for subsequent requests: it's a caching mechanism for images.

I'm storing the image data in a static dictionary like this:

```
public static class ImageCacheManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, byte[]> TheImageResponseCache = new Dictionary<string, byte[]>();
}
```

The HTTP module works, no bugs, but the content doesn't display the image because it's somehow corrupted. This is the full code:

```
public class ModuleImageCache : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
        context.EndRequest += OnEndRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication TheApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext TheContext = TheApplication.Context;

        string TheRequestUrl = TheContext.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (TheRequestUrl.Contains("/images/") == true &&
            ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache.ContainsKey(TheRequestUrl) == true)
        {
            byte[] cachedContent = ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache[TheRequestUrl];
            string contentType = DetermineContentType(TheRequestUrl);

            TheContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            TheContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", cachedContent.Length.ToString());
            TheContext.Response.BinaryWrite(cachedContent);
            TheContext.Response.End();
        }
    }

    private string DetermineContentType(string TheRequestUrl)
    {
        string TheFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(TheRequestUrl).ToLower();

        if (TheFileExtension == ".jpg" || TheFileExtension == ".jpeg") { return "image/jpeg"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".png") { return "image/png"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".svg") { return "image/jpeg"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".webp") { return "image/webp"; }

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

    private void OnEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication TheApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext TheContext = TheApplication.Context;

        string TheRequestUrl = TheContext.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (TheRequestUrl.Contains("/images/") == true)
        {
            using (MemoryStream capturedStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Stream originalResponseStream = TheContext.Response.Filter;

                TheContext.Response.Filter = capturedStream;
                TheContext.Response.Flush();
                TheContext.Response.Filter = originalResponseStream;

                if (ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache.ContainsKey(TheRequestUrl) == false)
                {
                    ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache[TheRequestUrl] = capturedStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the browser, the image doesn't display. The Chrome Inspector shows the request is working fine but the image is corrupted in the process. What could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you rolling your own caching logic?

Comment: So that I'll later be able to add extra functionalities.

Comment: Is the mime type properly set?

Comment: May be HTTP compression is the issue.

Comment: While may be not related to the problem - note that this implementation contains major flaw: it uses `TheImageResponseCache ` from multiple threads (multiple requests) in unsafe way, so at any moment it might break in totally unpredictable ways.

Comment: "somehow corrupted"  - any chance to get a screenshot of the response in the network tab of the devtools? all the response headers. and if possible, a link to an example corrupted image (and its original state)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is better to set the filter when the request is being taken in charge instead of when its process is finished, so we can put all the HttpModule logic in the BeginRequest event.

Due to this fact we also need to create a custom Stream implementation that wraps the default one. This will receive all the data from ASP.NET during the process and we'll store it in memory, then when the response is completed we'll put it in our cache.

```
public class ModuleImageCache : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication TheApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext TheContext = TheApplication.Context;

        string TheRequestUrl = TheContext.Request.Url.ToString();

        if (TheRequestUrl.Contains("/images/"))
        {
            if (ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache.ContainsKey(TheRequestUrl) == true)
            {
                byte[] cachedContent = ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache[TheRequestUrl];
                string contentType = DetermineContentType(TheRequestUrl);

                TheContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                TheContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", cachedContent.Length.ToString());
                TheContext.Response.BinaryWrite(cachedContent);
                TheContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                TheContext.Response.Filter = new CacheStream(TheContext.Response.Filter, data =>
                {   // This code will be executed when the response has been produced
                    if (ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache.ContainsKey(TheRequestUrl) == false)
                    {
                        ImageCacheManager.TheImageResponseCache[TheRequestUrl] = data;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private string DetermineContentType(string TheRequestUrl)
    {
        string TheFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(TheRequestUrl).ToLower();

        if (TheFileExtension == ".jpg" || TheFileExtension == ".jpeg") { return "image/jpeg"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".png") { return "image/png"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".svg") { return "image/jpeg"; }
        if (TheFileExtension == ".webp") { return "image/webp"; }

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }
}
```

And here is the CacheStream that wraps the default one adding a caching layer on it.

```
internal class CacheStream : Stream
{
    private readonly MemoryStream cacheStream = new MemoryStream();
    private readonly Stream stream;
    private readonly Action<byte[]> callback;

    public CacheStream(Stream stream, Action<byte[]> callback)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => stream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => stream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => stream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => stream.Length;

    public override long Position { get => stream.Position; set => stream.Position = value; }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        stream.Flush();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        return stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        cacheStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            cacheStream.Position = 0;
            callback(cacheStream.ToArray());
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            cacheStream.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see we just intercept Write calls and store that data. Then when ASP.NET disposes this object (so when it's done processing) we invoke the callback that we set in the HttpModule so we'll finally put the date in ImageCacheManager (this will probably need some improvements to handle concurrent requests)